Casting SObject record to Task object wipes out all related data
so I'm running into an issue where casting a SObject record to a Task wipes out all the related data even when the fields are included in the query. Is this due to it being a polymorphic relationship or what?
You can reproduce it by creating a new custom lookup field on the Activity object. I did Test_Contact__c which looks up to a contact record. Populate that field with a valid Id and then run the apex code below in the Developer Console and take a look at the logs.
You'll see the data come through in the query AND when serializing it into a JSON string. But when casted to a Task object, the contact's name is wiped from the record. You can also see the value in the variable assignment but not when it gets logged.
This causes the error: FAILURE: Invalid field Test_Contact__r.Name for Task when trying to access the field via
String contactName = (String) taskRecord.get('Test_Contact__r.Name');
List<SObject> records = [SELECT Id, Test_Contact__c, Test_Contact__r.Name FROM Task];
SObject taskRecord = (SObject) records.get(0);
System.debug('>>>>>>>>>> taskRecord: ' + taskRecord);


String jsonString = JSON.serialize(records.get(0));
Task taskRecordFromString = (Task) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Task.class);
System.debug('>>>>>>>>>> jsonString: ' + jsonString);
System.debug('>>>>>>>>>> taskRecordFromString: ' + taskRecordFromString);

Logs:
14:10:20:034 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [4]|mvn.taskRecord|{"Id":"00TRK000007u0GJ2AY","Test_Contact__c":"003RK00000SUToDYAX","RecordTypeId":"012RK000003ggOiYAI","Test_Contact__r":{"Id":"003RK00000SUToDYAX","Name":"Portal PP_HCP User 1","RecordTypeId":"012RK000003ghZwYAI"}}|0x30107ed

14:10:20:034 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|>>>>>>>>>> taskRecord: Task:{Id=00TRK000007u0GJ2AY, Test_Contact__c=003RK00000SUToDYAX, RecordTypeId=012RK000003ggOiYAI}

14:10:20:037 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [9]|mvn.taskRecordFromString|{"Test_Contact__r":{"RecordTypeId":"012RK000003ghZwYAI","attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v62.0 (36 more) ..."},"Id":"003RK00000SUToDYAX","Name":"Portal PP_HCP User 1"},"Test_Contact__c":"003RK00000SUToDYAX","RecordTypeId":"012RK000003ggOiYAI","attributes":{"type":"Tas

14:10:20:038 USER_DEBUG [11]|DEBUG|>>>>>>>>>> taskRecordFromString: Task:{Test_Contact__c=003RK00000SUToDYAX, RecordTypeId=012RK000003ggOiYAI, Id=00TRK000007u0GJ2AY}


After some more investigation I found that I'm still able to access the related record field even though it wasn't showing up in the logs. The one caveat being how the value is retrieved
Invalid field error:
String contactName = (String) taskRecord.get('Test_Contact__r.Name');
Works just fine:
String contactName = (String)taskRecord.getSObject('Test_Contact__r').get('Name');

Yep, that's definitely a downside of using untyped deserialization for SObject types (or just working with generic SObjects in general). In a similar vein, if you have a subquery, you'd need to use SObject's .getSObjects() method (plural instead of singular) to retrieve the child records.

... worth getting familiar with all the SObject methods.

Likely cause is the specific behaviour of the deserialization methods.
Try JSON.deserializeUntyped instead:
Task taskRecordFromString = (Task) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

Your JSON.deserialize has been told that you only want a Task.class result whereas JSON.deserializeUntyped is likely to also follow the relationship to the Contact and include that object too.
I assume your are using serialize/deserialize to investigate a problem as it isn't needed in the code your have posted. Direct casting works fine e.g.:
Task typedTaskRecord = (Task) taskRecord;


Yep, I'm using serialize/deserialize to investigate the issue of, FAILURE: Invalid field Test_Contact__r.Name for Task after casting the variable and trying to access the custom field. Both approaches, direct casting and JSON deserialization cause the error. Sorry for not making that clear in the code block.
Task typedTaskRecord = (Task) taskRecord;
logs the same input as
SObject taskRecord = (SObject) records.get(0);
